Why does iOS Google Translate not use autocorrect in the source language field?
Whenever I'm using Google Translate, the source language field doesn't use autocorrect.
For example: when I translate from English to any language, when I type English words, the app doesn't autocorrect any of the words (like "dont" to "don't", and all spelling errors).
This issue is not global to the entire app, since the Feedback input field uses autocorrect, as does almost every other app on the phone.
There are no app settings that correspond to autocorrect, and the autocorrect settings are enabled for the entire OS.
Solutions that have no effect:

Deleting the app and reinstalling, where all data is confirmed deleted by noticing that the translation history is gone
Rebooting the phone
Toggling autocorrect off and on again in the global iOS settings

Equivalent questions with no useful answers:

Apple Support Community: Autocorrect Simply Doesn't Work in Several Scenarios


The obvious explanation is google chose a value of false for the Boolean that enables this feature. Is there a deeper question you have or is this just asking if a developer of an app can control this on a field by field basis?

Also you are asking a question that is likely off-topic here on AD. "Why" questions are not answerable as companies don't explain themselves (usually) to end users.
